# Is it possible to import JS code from a HTML file?

Tags: javascript

This is a continuation of my efforts to troubleshoot the problems [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71973630/how-do-i-run-svg-editor-without-using-node-js) where I am trying to understand how to run a Node.js application which the author is saying that it can be run straight from the webserver (ES6 ?)

As you can see I am receiving some errors from my browser
[image]

After diving into [the sources of the app](https://github.com/SVG-Edit/svgedit) (which might be too much for my level) I am seeing this line
`import editorTemplate from './templates/editorTemplate.html'`
and [the file in question](https://github.com/SVG-Edit/svgedit/blob/master/src/editor/templates/editorTemplate.html) is indeed a text/html file and there is nothing to import from there
The above strange (to me) import is attempted here
https://github.com/SVG-Edit/svgedit/blob/master/src/editor/EditorStartup.js

Is this a mistake ?

Comment: I'm quite sure that if you rename the ./templates/editorTemplate.html into ./templates/editorTemplate.esm and import that instead it will work.

Comment: Any explanation for that? Even if I rename the files the imported objects are not there...How is this going to work

Answer (score 0):

The key problem is that you are attempting to load the raw `src` files. They are not runnable JS files. You will need to serve the bundled `dist`ribution files that were output by the project's build pipeline.

In particular, the project is using [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/), and [has configured it](https://github.com/SVG-Edit/svgedit/blob/master/rollup.config.js) to use the [`rollup-plugin-html`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-html). It will inline the html as a string in the script.